Regex how to match and insert comma into number
Sorry for asking newbie question but I have been researching for hours and I found that regex is too hard for me.
I am trying to match something with lookahead and behind and insert comma into these number.
Lets say trying to match numbers first in ABC2345.67DEF with (?<=ABC)(.*?)(?=DEF)
But I want to insert a comma 3 digit before dot and look like this
2,345.67 instead of 2345.67
any help would be greatly appreciated

Like this? \d(?=(?:\d{3})+\.) https://regex101.com/r/pH9YGm/1

A variant of @Thefourthbird's suggestion is to replace (zero-width) matches of (?<=\d)(?=(?:\d{3})+\.) with a comma. Demo

regex for what language or tool? Please read the "how to ask?" section in the regex Wiki.

To place a comma when there are 1 or more repetitions of 3 digits to the right followed by a dot:
\d(?=(?:\d{3})+\.)

The pattern matches:

\d Match a single digit
(?= Positive lookahead, assert that what is to the right of the current position is

(?:\d{3})+ Repeat 1 or more times matching 3 digits
\. Match a dot


) Close the lookahead

In the replacement you can use the full match followed by a comma.
For example in PHP you can use $0, or JavaScript $&, or Python \g<0>,
See a regex demo.

If you want a single regex and account for the ABC and DEF part, you might use a regex in a language where an infinite quantifier in a lookbehind assertion is supported.
Then you could use (?<=ABC\d*) where you would assert ABC to the left followed by 0+ times a digit.
 (?<=ABC\d*)\d(?=(?:\d{3})+\.\d+DEF) 

See another regex demo.
For example in JavaScript if a lookbehind is supported:


const regex = /(?<=ABC\d*)\d(?=(?:\d{3})+\.\d+DEF)/g;
const str = `ABC2345.67DEF
ABC999992345.67DEF
ABD999992345.67DEF`;

const result = str.replace(regex, "$&,");

console.log(result);




You need to extract numbers from the string and then add commas into the numbers. To do this, I updated your old regx to extract numbers. And then, inserted commas using another regx. I provide my code.
const test = 'ABC2345.67DEF';
const result = test.match(/(?<=ABC)(\d+)(\.\d+)(?=DEF)/);

const numbersBeforeDecimal = result[1].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
const numbersAfterDecimal = result[2];

const updatedResult = `ABC${numbersBeforeDecimal}${numbersAfterDecimal}DEF`;


I cannot see the [javascript] tag under the question.

Do you really want to do it using regex? Because there's a simpler way to do so by using this:
let's say your number is number = "2345.67" after removing all letters using the regex you have provided. Then:
formattedNumber = parseFloat(number).toLocaleString('en-US'); 

Which formats the number according to a specific locale. The 'en-US' option specifies U.S. English conventions, which include using commas to separate thousands and using point as a decimal separator.
Hope this helps!! If you would like to do it using regex, let me know !!

I cannot see the [javascript] tag under the question.
